# How to use macro command to judge whether BibTex or Biber is used to compile Bib file？

Tags: biblatex, xetex, biber

Such as the title， Automatically detect what the current editor is using to compile the bib file, for example, I use Texstudio, how to use the macro command to know whether I am using Biber or BibTex

eg：

```
\ifbiber
    %% writing
\fi


\ifbibtex
    %% writing
\fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can realistically query with TeX code from your `.tex` document if your editor is set up to run BibTeX or Biber (if your editor exposes this info in some config file, you might be able to read this config file with some shell escape and parse the info, but that seems very, very difficult and shell escape comes with its own set of security risks).

Here is what you can try and do from LaTeX.

You can check if the last run on your document was with Biber or BibTeX. To this end we have a look at the `.blg` file and see if it starts off telling

> ```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d
> ```

or

> ```
> [0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
> ```

Things got a bit messy because we have to account for the correct category codes when reading, but the following should be usable. The problem with this is that you can only detect *after the fact* which bibliography engine was run. You cannot detect which engine will/should be run.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newread\cbe@blgin

\begingroup
\gundef\cbe@firstline
\openin\cbe@blgin\jobname.blg\relax
\ifeof\cbe@blgin
\else
  \endlinechar\m@ne
  \global\readline\cbe@blgin to \cbe@firstline
\fi
\closein\cbe@blgin

\gdef\ecb@expandfirsttwo#1#2#3{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\noexpand#1#2#3}\reserved@a}

\xdef\ecb@thisisbiber{\detokenize{This is Biber}}
\expandafter\gdef
\expandafter\IfBiberUsedTF@i
\expandafter#\expandafter1
\ecb@thisisbiber #2\biberteststop{\notblank{#2}}
\gdef\IfBiberUsedTF{%
  \ifundef\cbe@firstline
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\ecb@expandfirsttwo\IfBiberUsedTF@i\cbe@firstline\ecb@thisisbiber\biberteststop}}

\xdef\ecb@thisisbibtex{\detokenize{This is BibTeX}}
\expandafter\gdef
\expandafter\IfBibTeXUsedTF@i
\expandafter#\expandafter1
\ecb@thisisbibtex #2\bibtexteststop{\notblank{#2}}
\gdef\IfBibTeXUsedTF{%
  \ifundef\cbe@firstline
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\ecb@expandfirsttwo\IfBibTeXUsedTF@i\cbe@firstline\ecb@thisisbibtex\bibtexteststop}}
\endgroup
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\IfBiberUsedTF{Biber}{No Biber}

\IfBibTeXUsedTF{BibTeX}{No BibTeX}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to check which engine should be run (because of the packages you load), you can use that Biber can only be used with `biblatex` and only if the user does not specify `backend=bibtex,`. So we can check for those conditions

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\ecb@ifbibtex\@firstoftwo
\let\ecb@ifbiber\@secondoftwo

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}
    {\iftoggle{blx@bibtex}
       {}
       {\let\ecb@ifbibtex\@secondoftwo
        \let\ecb@ifbiber\@firstoftwo}}
    {}}

\newcommand*{\IfBiberTF}{\ecb@ifbiber}
\newcommand*{\IfBibTeXTF}{\ecb@ifbibtex}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\IfBiberTF{Use Biber}{Do not use Biber}

\IfBibTeXTF{Use BibTeX}{Do not use BibTeX}
\end{document}
```